# C++ nested class which inherits from the outer class; Incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++, enums, algebraic-data-types

In kotlin, there is a design pattern wherein you can mimic a swift enum with associated values using a sealed class, and inheriting from it with a nested class

https://medium.com/@da_pacheco/using-kotlins-sealed-class-to-approximate-swift-s-enum-with-associated-data-7e0abac88bbf

E.g.; Swift has:

```
enum Barcode {
  case UPCA(Int, Int, Int, Int)
  case QRCode(String)
}
```

Kotlin  mimics:

```
sealed class Barcode {
  class UPCA(val system: Int, val manufacturer: Int, val product: Int, val check: Int) : Barcode()
  class QRCode(val productCode: String) : Barcode()
}
```

And then you can do things like have a list of `Barcode` and iterate through them all.

You can also use this pattern in Java and C#... there's no "sealed classes" so you can't stop future people extending the list, but it's close enough and it's quite handy.

So now I'm trying to do this in C++, and I get the error message "Incomplete type is not allowed"

```
class ActionToPerform
{
public:
  class ClearItems: public ActionToPerform
  { };
};
```

This makes some amount of sense in that the `ActionToPerform` type isn't fully declared at the point which the compiler encouters `ClearItems`, however it's also dumb and annoying. I can move the `ClearItems` class out of `ActionToPerform` but then I lose the scoping/namespacing benefit.

Is there some way around this? or is this just an inherent limit that C++ has?

Comment: I am not sure, since I don't know much about either Swift or Kotlin, but it seems to me that you really don't want inheritance, but `std::variant`. It allows you to have a type that can hold any of a compile-time fixed list of types at runtime and `std::visit` can be used to act dependent on the type that the `std::variant` holds, similar to how the `switch` for the swift case is explained in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html. Inheritance is only really useful if you are going to have a common virtual interface in the base class.

Comment: std::variant sounds like exactly what I want. That's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just forward declare your derived class:

```
class ActionToPerform
{
public:
  class ClearItems;
};

class ActionToPerform::ClearItems: public ActionToPerform
{ };
```

Comment: Wow I would have never thought of this. Thanks!